# What's the correct way to read Lottie animation from document directory

Tags: ios, swift, lottie

I'm trying to store json in document directory and then read to display Lottie animation.

This is how I write json in document

```
        if let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory,
                                                            in: .userDomainMask).first {
            let pathWithFilename = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("myJsonString.json")
            
            do {
                try jsonString.write(to: pathWithFilename, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
            } catch {
                
            }
        }
```

This is how I read it

```
            let checkMarkAnimation =  AnimationView(filePath: "\(pathWithFilename)")
            animationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            self.animationView.addSubview(checkMarkAnimation)
            checkMarkAnimation.frame = self.animationView.bounds
            checkMarkAnimation.loopMode = .loop
            checkMarkAnimation.play()
```

I exactly know that this is working json, also when I print Data(contentsOf: pathWithFilename), it prints actual json but when I assign it in animation with AnimationView(filePath:) it doesn't work.

Comment: try `let checkMarkAnimation = Animation.filepath(yourfilepath)` and then assign to `animationView.animation = checkMarkAnimation`

Comment: @KishanBhatiya doesn't work

Comment: Are you getting the file path?

Comment: Yes, and also can take its content

Comment: just check by adding the lottie json locally and then using it by setting its animation property. so that at least you'll be sure that issue with using lottie from documentsDirectory and not with your view hierarchy.

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati I did, and it works locally :(

Comment: I have tried as Kishan Bhatiya told and is working for me. I think there is some issue the way you're using it. try to use path like - AnimationView(filePath: pathWithFilename.path)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue with the way you're using the filePath. As pathWithFilename is URL, instead of using it like `"\(pathWithFilename)"`, you should use it like - `pathWithFilename.path`.

Below will work for you,

```
let checkMarkAnimation =  AnimationView(filePath: pathWithFilename.path)
animationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
self.animationView.addSubview(checkMarkAnimation)
checkMarkAnimation.frame = self.animationView.bounds
checkMarkAnimation.loopMode = .loop
checkMarkAnimation.play()
```